# How to disable selected values from getting displayed in input bar in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];

const Option = props => { 
  //const temp = "some";
  //
  return ( 
  <div> 
    <components.Option {...props}> 
      <input type="checkbox" checked={props.isSelected} onChange={() => null} /> 
      <label>{props.value}</label> 
    </components.Option>
  </div> 
  ); 
};
```

Currently my code looks like above, what it does is, it is displaying something like this
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOXi8.png)

I don't want to display selected values in search input bar.Is there any way to disable selected option from getting displayed in input bar ?

Code for Select Bar

```
<Select components={{ Option }} isMulti closeMenuOnSelect={false} hideSelectedOptions={false} options={options} />
```

Comment: You will have to manually filter out selected values and display remaining

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is a new props `controlShouldRenderValue = { false }` then it will not display selected option in input bar, even after selecting option from drop down list as mention below

```
<Select
 components={{ Option }}
 isMulti closeMenuOnSelect={false}
 hideSelectedOptions={false}
 controlShouldRenderValue = { false }
 options={options} />
```

So, in the search box it will display placeholder

Comment: God bless you, looking 5 hours for this, maybe react-select authors need to re-name this property

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's to do with the `hideSelectedOptions` prop you're passing into the `Select` component here:

`<Select hideSelectedOptions={false} />`

I would try setting it to `true` (or removing it) and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I saw your other comment @rajesh before you deleted it. I don't think it's conducive to helping people when you jump down people's throats when they are trying to help. Your above response was sent about 15 seconds after I made the post, and then the followup you deleted accused me of missing the point of the post when you hadn't checked to see if the solution would solve the issue. Please spend more time trying to help and less time trying to police people, it's damaging to the community.

Comment: Dear friend, I'm no one to accuse/ *jump to people's throats*. Yes I deleted my comment but that was because I realized, it was I that was wrong. Also about *police people* comment, someone has to monitor activities. And as SO is users portal, users' will have to do it. I do not discourage people, but at the same time, I try to minimize spoon-feeding and redundant stuff. Soon you will be rewarded with privileges and it is expected from you to be strict as well. It will keep our community clean

Comment: I disagree, you've discouraged me. I can't see how anyone who isn't afforded even 30 seconds to fix their post wouldn't be discouraged either. There is of course value in ensuring the answers meet a certain level of quality, but I think we disagree on what that means. Let's leave it there.

Comment: Thanks for response @ollie , but i believe i am not able to frame my question correctly , i dont want selected option to get displayed in input bar , even after selecting option from drop down list , my placeholder should remain as is , and selected option shouldn't be displayed there.

Comment: @YashChauhan ah ok, could you update the question with the code for the input bar - it looks like the component you've supplied is only for the elements in the drop down list as I can't see an input field (only the checkboxes). The idea will be similar - you want to filter the list displayed by if they're *not* selected

Comment: I wen through documentation for React-Select but unable to find props which is responsible to adding selected option in search input bar.

Comment: Is it this option you're passing in `hideSelectedOptions={false}`? It seems to describe the behaviour you have currently.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to define the custom component with an empty div

```js
const MultiValueContainer = props => {
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
};

class PriceFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return [
      <Select
        isMulti
        components={{ MultiValueContainer }}
        options={this.props.options}
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      />
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply render out your options only if their `isSelected` is false, and in the other case, send out an empty `div` using a ternary condition :

```
const Option = props => {
    return !props.isSelected ?
        <div>
            <components.Option {...props}>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={props.isSelected} onChange={() => null} />
                <label>{props.value}</label>
            </components.Option>
        </div>
        :
        <div/>
};
```

You will have to return a JSX node in every cases, returning `null` (or an equivalent) will generate a warning/error.

Comment: Thanks for response @Treycos , but i believe i am not able to frame my question correctly , i dont want selected option to get displayed in input bar , even after selecting option from drop down list , my placeholder should remain as is , and selected option shouldn't be displayed there.

Comment: @YashChauhan did you get the solution, I do have the same question